# Why do I keep having a "Not found" error when I call these methods?

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask in Python and I am trying to elaborate post requests on the server I am hosting (atm on localhost because I am still trying to make it work).

The post message is generated in the following way:

```
payload = {'k' : '123' }
r = requests.post ('http://localhost', payload)
```

and then the result I get is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

At the same time, if I try to send the same request to the address localhost/post as follows

```
r2  = requests.post ('http://localhost/post', data)
```

the result becomes

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

The code I am using to create the server is the following:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, Request
from flask.templating import render_template
from flask.globals import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index ():
    return render_template('indexServer.html')

@app.route('/post', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def post():
    return render_template('response.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = 'localhost', port = 80, debug = True)
```

Now, while the GET method in the index function works, it doesn't when I try to get the '/post' page. I guess the reason behind this is also the same for which I get 404 above when I try to post.

I'd like to understand why this is happening, as I can't figure out what is going on and what I am doing wrong. If it wasn't already obvious, I have just started working in Python with Flask so it may be anything.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Does the GET request on `/` return `indexServer.html` ?

Comment: Are your HTML files in the "templates" subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine - looks to me like your Flask application isn't actually listening on port 80 as you expect it to.

There could be many reasons for this - perhaps an existing process is already using port `80` and therfore your flask application cannot bind to it. Or in many OSes, you need to run the process as `root` to bind to a port less than `1024`. What I would recommend is you change the bind port to `8088`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = 'localhost', port = 8088, debug = True)
```

and then try your requests again:

```
r2  = requests.post ('http://localhost:8088/post', data)
```

Comment: It worked, in the end the problem was the port. Thanks!